# Oauth to SharePoint online from a SaS application

Tags: sharepoint-online, oauth

I am building a Software as a Service application, and I want my users to be able to authorise the webpage to upload files directly to their sharepoint document library.

I imagine the flow working like this:

- User Logs into my Webpage
- User clicks authorise SharePoint.
- User set to SharePoint and logs in, SharePoint asks to confirm permissions.
- Token returned and saved by webpage
- Webpage then uploads files directly to document library

The problem I am having at the moment, is all the documentation I am seeing, only allows this flow if the user has registered an app in their SharePoint site using /_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx.

I will have many users, all with different sharepoint tenants, is there a authorization flow I can use for this situation?

*update* I'm aware I could do this using flow and a custom trigger, but I'm trying to make it as simple for the end user as possible

Comment: Did you try with Azure AD application & Microsoft Graph permissions? Check if Graph APIs supports the operations you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for "[Manage Application Permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-cloud-apps/manage-app-permissions)"